# How to populate monthly data to weekly data in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to populate data in dataframe which consists of monthly data like the followings

```
M      A    B    C
2020-1 2    30   5
2020-2 8    50   9
```

How can I do this easily using pandas api?

```
M          A    B    C
2020-1-01  2    30   5
2020-1-08  3    35   6
2020-1-15  5    40   7
2020-1-22  7    45   8
2020-2-01  8    50   9
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by months with `W` for weekends and `ffill` for forward filling values and then some processing with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), multiple and add values to columns:

```
df['M'] = pd.to_datetime(df['M'])
df = df.set_index('M').resample('W').ffill()
s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).cumcount().to_numpy()

df['B'] = df['B'].add(df.C.mul(s))
df[['A','C']] = df[['A','C']].add(s, axis=0)
df['B'] = df['B']
print (df)
            A   B  C
M                   
2020-01-05  2  30  5
2020-01-12  3  35  6
2020-01-19  4  40  7
2020-01-26  5  45  8
2020-02-02  8  50  9
```

Comment: @verystrongjoe - datetimes not match, is it problem?